# JQuery - how to use the hover() event on a list of DIVs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="panel">
  <div class="listing" id="ref_1">...</div>
  <div class="listing" id="ref_2">...</div>
  <div class="listing" id="ref_3">...</div>
  <div class="listing" id="ref_4">...</div>
</div>
```

What I should like to do is, when someone hovers over a `div.listing`, to `alert()` to the screen the `id` name.

Meaning, if a person hovers over with their mouse the `id="ref_3"`, to `alert("ref_3")`;

**Question**: How do I do this with JQuery/Javascript?

**UPDATE**:

Linked below is the live site. As you'll see, none of the answers below work. (Line 340)

http://tinyurl.com/ybbey4

Any recommendation?

Comment: that's pretty rough: this is BillyJ 's first post. The downvoters could at least explain his decision and argument. Personally when i read your question, i was like: well, that's really easy basic jquery stuff. Did he actually try? But the question is clear and well formulated and obviously you had an issue so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.listing').bind('mouseover',function(){
alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

You can see this code working [here](http://jsbin.com/ukuwi).

UPDATE

looking at your code, you might want to try this instead:

```
$('.hlisting').live('mouseover',function(){
alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: Won't this cause problems on the mouseout? I thought the "hover" binding provided you the ability to give functions for over and out...

Comment: no, it won't cause any problem. hover is nice if you want to trigger an event for both mouseenter and mouseleave .

Comment: I receive the following error:  $("#panel div.listing").mouseOver is not a function

Comment: This does not work. I've updated my original post to link to my live site to show how it does not work.

Comment: BillyJ: the code i posted works. You can see it running on a live test. So the error is on your page somewhere. I don't see the inclusion of jquery in your code. Please learn to be more specific in your replies than just "it does not work". To be frank, it makes you sound like a cry-baby.

Comment: JQuery is in combined.min.1.4.1.js. I am using Firebug but can't find any errors being reported. I'm completely confused as to why it's not working.

Comment: i'd suggest you try with a normal jquery load (using the < script> tag and see if that make it work. In the meanwhile i'll have a closer look at your page source code.

Comment: Many thanks @pixeline. I'll create another page while you look at my code in more detail that has JQuery pulled from Google

Comment: i think i got it: try replaceing "bind" by "live" and tell me if that works. I think your div.hlisting are not available when the page first loads. They get inserted after some action i guess. So, use "live()" to attach the behaviour to any div.hlisting when created.

Comment: Thanks, glad i could help. Do you understand the problem now? It's a classic (that's why the jquery team thought of the "live()" binding system). Very useful in ajax application where the dom is modified heavily according to the user manipulations.

Comment: Most definitely and I'm learning more and more about JQuery everyday. In case you hadn't noticed, I use JQuery quite a bit in my app. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

better yet

```
$('#panel div.listing').mouseover(function() {
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

this works

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head><title>test</title>
<style type="text/css">
.listing { width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px black solid; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("jquery", "1.4.1");
  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    $('#panel div.listing').mouseover(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
  });
</script></head>
<div id="panel">
  <div class="listing" id="ref_1">...</div>
  <div class="listing" id="ref_2">...</div>
  <div class="listing" id="ref_3">...</div>
  <div class="listing" id="ref_4">...</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would that be better? mouseOver() calls bind(), so it's bound to be slightly less fast. Also, your selector does not make the traversing less intense, according to tests.

Comment: ty munch

but pixeline i thought that it used jquery uses javascript's getElementsByTagName(), so the tag "div" in fron makes the class selector faster, and using the ID before that should be even more specific? can you reference me the test?

Comment: I receive the following error: $("#panel div.listing").mouseOver is not a function

Comment: it's lowercase mouseover, i fixed it

Comment: This does not work. I've updated my original post to link to my live site to show how it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you currently using $ as a function in other script file, and not using noConflict

Comment: This does not work. I've updated my original post to link to my live site to show how it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

BillyJ, it sounds like you maybe aren't loading up the jQuery library in your HTML file.

Be sure to include `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` in your file before calling the above function.

Comment: This does not work. I've updated my original post to link to my live site to show how it does not work.

Comment: Here's the problem I'm seeing with your live page:

On line 341, you're looking for a div with class="hlisting" and on line 345, you're looking for a div with class="listing" but in the body of your document, you don't have anything with either of those classes. (It looks like you create some with JavaScript later on, but I don't see any on the page linked above.)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine separate from your site...

I'd suggest just adding a div in the code with a `hslisting` class. Don't use JS to inject it. See if something about the way you are injecting it is causing problems.

http://jsbin.com/agosa works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The 'mouseenter' event is usually a better choice than 'mouseover'. From 
http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/ :

> "The mouseenter event differs from mouseover in the way it handles event bubbling. If mouseover were used in this example, then when the mouse pointer moved over the Inner element, the handler would be triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The mouseenter event, on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse enters the element it is bound to, not a descendant."

```
jQuery('#panel div.listing').bind('mouseenter',function(){
  alert(this.id);
  return false;
});
```